# TestNG Executable JAR files

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is the TestNG Executable JAR files alone is enough to work with TestNG framework or the TestNG plugin is essential? I have the JAR files, can i add to my library and work with TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

Plugin just simplifies running things.  You do not need it so to say.  But, if you say want to run a single test or a suite file - a plugin would give you a simple way to right click and trigger it off.  But with no plugin you will have to run with the java run command or through maven command if that's what you are running.

So the answer is yes - you can run but the plugin will always help while you are developing your tests.

Comment: ok.. but i tried to run a small snipet by just adding those jar files to library.. it throws error:" You need to specify at least one testng.xml, one class or one method".. Could you please help me in executing by just using those TestNG jar files..

Comment: How are you triggerring your testcases?